# Button in popup that get selected text - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In my popup.html in my chrome extension I have a button that will get the selected text in de webpage and put it in my textarea in the popup.html.

1. First I select text in a webpage
2. I click on my extension. An popup will show with a textarea and a button.
3. When I Push the button the selected text will show in my textarea.

is someone who can help me with this issue,

Thanks,

Wouter

Comment: Hi Wouter, what is the issue? Do you want to implement that? Or that is what you have done already?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to implement that, you would need to use a couple of API's.

You need to make sure of [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) in order to capture selection within the DOM. Then you need to use [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to let the Popup communicate to the Content Script. After you do all that, you can simply use [chrome.tabs.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest) to send a message to the Content Script so that you get back a response with the data.

For example, this is how you can do a Popup that fetches the current selection:

### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body { width: 300px; }
  textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
</style>
<script>
function pasteSelection() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) {
      var text = document.getElementById('text'); 
      text.innerHTML = response.data;
    });
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="text"> </textarea>
<button onclick="pasteSelection(); ">Paste Selection</button>
</body>
</html>
```

### selection.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getSelection")
      sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

### manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "Selected Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Selected Text",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "online.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "chrome://favicon/",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["selection.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example with code. But according to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16,  chrome.tabs.getSelected is deprecated and might stop working anytime. Use chrome.tabs.query() instead.