# Chrome Extension get selected text

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to get the selected text into my Chrome extension.

I want to ex. select a text in facebook feed and when I click my icon it will get it and show the selected text in my Extension.

I got this so far:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: "alert(window.getSelection().toString());"
})
```

it gets the selected text and alert it with a message in Chrome. However I want to show it in my html popup. I want to write it out like this:

```
document.getElementById("output").value = "Selected text here(but how)"
```

Need help! and I know there is other question about this, but they didn't give me exactly what I want..

Comment: This is what I ended up with:

        chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"window.getSelection().toString();"},
                function(results){
                document.getElementById("output").value = results;
        }

Works!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the last expression evaluated by the executed code in a callback function:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  document.getElementById("output").value = selection[0];
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work in same-origin frames and different-origin frames.

Also it freqently returns text that is not actually selected because focus in different frame now.

Also it doesn't work in input fields but that's not a problem:
`code
 let el = activeWindow.document.activeElement;
 if (isTextElem(el)) {
  if ('selectionStart' in el && el.selectionStart !== el.selectionEnd) {
   return el.value.substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
  }
 }
`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using [**Extensions Messaging**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). Basically, your "background page" will send the request to your service. For example, lets say you have a "popup" and once you click on it, it will do a "Google search" which is your service.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getSelection")
      sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Some References

1. [Creating a chrome extension which takes highlighted text on the page and inserts it into a textarea in popup.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349263/creating-a-chrome-extension-which-takes-highlighted-text-on-the-page-and-inserts#answer-14351458)

Or you can use this plugin

2. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-selection-source/fbhgckgfljgjkkfngcoeajbgndkeoaaj

Comment: This wont send it out to my html doc ?

Comment: Uncaught Error: extension.sendRequest, extension.onRequest, and extension.onRequestExternal are deprecated. Please use runtime.sendMessage, runtime.onMessage, and runtime.onMessageExternal instead.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 8.2 I use this code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( { code: 'window.getSelection().toString();'}, selectedText => {
 (document.getElementById('text-input') as HTMLInputElement).value = selectedText[0];
  console.log(selectedText[0]);
});
```