# Is it possible to make use of chrome.tts.speak() within chrome.tabs.executeScript()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

I am currently in the process of producing a chrome extension that features numerous accessibility tools, one such tool is Text To Speech. So far for every tool I have made use of `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, code{''}`, however text to speech requires the use of `chrome.tts.speak()`. Is it possible to use `chrome.tts.speak()` within `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, code{''})`?

I am able to get selected text from the web as confirmed through the use of `var text = window.getSelection(); alert(text);` and the text to speech tool function does work as it is able to read aloud text I input manually. The problem therefore lies in carrying the variable taken from the web to `chrome.tts.speak()'.

I have made various attempts at combining both but have been unable to do so.

Attempt 1 - `return text;` does not work in this context

```
function getText(e) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
   {code:'var text = window.getSelection(); return text;'});
}


function speakText(e) {
  chrome.tts.speak(GetText(), {'lang': 'en-GB', 'gender': 'female', 
 'rate': 1.0});
}
```

Attempt 2 - 'var text' does carrying out with `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`

```
   function getText(e) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
   {code:'var text = window.getSelection();'});
   return text;
 }


 function speakText(e) {
  chrome.tts.speak(GetText(), {'lang': 'en-GB', 'gender': 'female', 
 'rate': 1.0});
 }
```

Attempt 3 - The selection from the web is not stored without the use of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

```
function getText(e) {
   var text = window.getSelection();
   return text;
}


function speakText(e) {
  chrome.tts.speak(GetText(), {'lang': 'en-GB', 'gender': 'female', 
'rate': 1.0});
}
```

Attempt 4 - Breaks everything

```
function getText(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
  {code:'var text = window.getSelection(); chrome.tts.speak(text, 
{'lang': 'en-GB', 'gender': 'female', 'rate': 1.0});'});
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. `code:'window.getSelection().toString()'` 2. use tts in the executeScript's callback because content scripts can use only [4 chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: 3. chrome API is asynchronous. Usage example: [Chrome Extension get selected text](//stackoverflow.com/a/19165930) -

Comment: Thanks for the help, from your advice i have change the code to this         `function getText(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"}, function(selection) {
    chrome.tts.speak(selection, {'lang': 'en-GB', 'gender': 'female','rate': 1.0});
  });
}`     however it still does not work, do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: See the types of the callback parameter in the documentation - it's an array so you need to take its 0 element.

Comment: It works perfectly now thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension get selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164474/chrome-extension-get-selected-text)