# Chrome extension getSelection not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension which only consist of a button. When this button is clicked, it should make an alert box which contains the highlighted textarea on a page. I can't get it to work. I can make it alert a hardcoded string, but not make it alert some highlighted text / selected textarea on a page.

Here is the javascript code **popup.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
test.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var selObj = document.getSelection(); 
    alert(selObj);

  }, false);
}, false);
```

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test ",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

**popup.html**
<

```
!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getSelection()` returns an object, not plain text. What does `alert(selObj.anchorNode.data)` print?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension get selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164474/chrome-extension-get-selected-text)

Comment: See also [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567).

Comment: It prints nothing, the alert even stops showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch the selection by loading a script into the page using the [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method in the Tabs API. You may have to add the `tabs` permission to your manifest.json.

To execute the script you first need to fetch the tab ID, you can do that using [`query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) and querying on fetching the active tab in the current window.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const test = document.querySelector('#test');
    test.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { code: `document.getSelection().toString()` }, (result) => {
                alert(result);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

Comment: ActiveTab permission might be enough since getting selection from non-active tab most likely unnecessary

Comment: i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" when i try your code

Comment: @studentcoder Ah yes, I updated the code now. I moved the line `const test = document.querySelector("#test");` into the document eventlistener. Try that instead.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov yes that seems to be true. Thanks for pointing it out.