# Get selection from PDF files in browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to get selection from PDF files.

I'm firing `window.getSelection()`. It's always empty in Chrome's default PDF handler. But with [pdf.js](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) extension, it works well from developer console.

My extension has access to file urls. (I added permission for `file://*/*`, `<all_urls>`) But still I can't retrieve text from pdf with my extension. My extension uses [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767429/button-in-popup-that-get-selected-text-chrome-extension) to get selection from page. (I use that method with [updated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new#16) API rules)

Comment: What about pdf.js. I can retrieve getSelection as expected in documents opened with pdf.js. It runs under chrome-extension url.

Comment: [How can I get selected text in pdf in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61076303)